# Using Babel.js and concat with gulp the generated source maps are incorrect

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, babeljs

I'm using gulp to transform JS with Babel 6, and after that, concat all the files on one (without any kind of uglify, only join the files). However to allow me to debug the application, I need the correct source maps, especially from the code transformed from Babel. Unfortunately, the source maps never look correct, since things like breakpoints on browser (Chrome or Firefox for instance) didn't match with the real code.

I'm using the following code on gulp:

```
return gulp.src( [].concat( FOLDERS.SOURCE.LIBS, FOLDERS.SOURCE.MODULES, FOLDERS.SOURCE.APP ) , {base: __dirname})
        .pipe( plumber() )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}) )
        .pipe( gulpif ( notLib, babel( {
            presets: [ 'es2015', 'stage-3' ],
            sourceMaps: "both"
        } ) ) )
        .pipe( replace("'use strict';", ""))
        .pipe( concat( FOLDERS.TARGET.DEVELOPMENT, {
         newLine: ';'
         } ) )
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write( './', {
            //addComment: true,
            sourceMappingURL: function (file){
                return path.basename(file.relative) + '.map?t=' + new Date().getTime();
            }
        }))
        .pipe( gulp.dest( FOLDERS.TARGET.DEV ) );
```

Where each element of FOLDERS.SOURCE is an array of paths to js files. The notLib is a simple function, that will ensure that the external libs aren't passed under babel (it is causing some errors on that case).

Can someone help me understand what can be wrong? Even, if I comment the concat code, generating multiple files, and referencing them on the page, the source map for some stills incorrect.

Comment: Concatenating JS is not a good idea. Have you considered using a bundler like Browserify or Webpack?

Comment: I'm updating a project that is already using the concat. My objective it to slowly move the code to ES6. That will force me now to seek and analyze all dependencies... It is why I would prefer to keep the concat, at least for now.

Comment: Any luck on this one? I'm having the same issue, and it is driving me crazy.

Comment: No @azurelogic . I have abandoned the idea of using sourcemaps. I think I have tried almost everything. So now every time I got an error, or want to do debug, I need to map mentally on which code it corresponds that portion of code and use that...